# Normal that Visual Studio is breaking on thrown FaultException at WCF Service operation?

Tags: wcf

In my service operation, I'm throwing a FaultException but the application halts until I press F5 to continue the operation.

Is this normal for FaultExceptions? (I can disable FaultExceptions from being caught in Visual Studio and everything works fine but I worry how this will work out in production?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is your debugger's behavior, not your app's behavior.  If you disable breaking on exceptions in Visual Studio, you see how your app will behave in production.